# Is there any law against bribing an elector?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college, faithless-elector

Is there any law against bribing an elector of the US Electoral College or against an elector accepting a bribe (other than the laws against violating their pledge)?

Comment: I don't have any citations for you, but its illegal to bribe state and federal officials, and electoral are defined by a mixture of state and federal laws, so it would almost certainly fall into existing state/federal bribery laws.

Answer (score 2):

Found a reference elsewhere which led me to 52 USC 10307:

> (c) False information in registering or voting; penalties Whoever
>   knowingly or willfully gives false information as to his name, address
>   or period of residence in the voting district for the purpose of
>   establishing his eligibility to register or vote, or conspires with
>   another individual for the purpose of encouraging his false
>   registration to vote or illegal voting, or **pays or offers to pay or
>   accepts payment** either for registration to vote or **for voting shall be
>   fined not more than $10,000 or imprisoned not more than five years, or
>   both**: Provided, however, That this provision shall be **applicable only
>   to** general, special, or primary elections held solely or in part for
>   the purpose of selecting or **electing any candidate for the office of
>   President**, Vice President, presidential elector, Member of the United
>   States Senate, Member of the United States House of Representatives,
>   Delegate from the District of Columbia, Guam, or the Virgin Islands,
>   or Resident Commissioner of the Commonwealth of Puerto Rico.

Note that selecting a presidential elector is listed separately, so “electing any candidate for office of President” refers to the actual election of the President, that is, the vote of the Electoral College.